# Is there any way to mix plain text and HTML email on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing `Ruby on Rails` Tutorial https://www.learnenough.com/ruby-on-rails-6th-edition-tutorial/account_activation#sec-mailer_templates and i generated a `User` `mailer` for account activation.

Here is the code:

app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb

```
Hi <%= @user.name %>,

Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:

<%= edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb

```
<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>Hi <%= @user.name %>,</p>
<p>
Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
</p>

<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token,
                                                    email: @user.email) %>
```

I understand the differences between them ("HTML it’s the way web pages and email templates are coded so that text is formatted and images are added. Plain Text is regular text, with no formatting options such as bold, italics, underlines, or special layout options" source: https://www.cakemail.com/blog/html-vs-plain-text/),

But I don't get why have two files with the same embedded Ruby code. Can I mix them in one file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't mix the two of them in one file. Rails will render both the .text and .html variants of the template separately and then [deliver them together in a multipart email](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-multipart-emails). Clients capable of display HTML emails will see the HTML variant, while clients only capable of text will get the text.

You can provide only or the other template if desired, but if you use only text, then you can't use HTML (obviously), and if you use only HTML then clients incapable of HTML display will display the HTML source code as the message, making it effectively unreadable. If your email is simple and there is no need for markup, then you can provide just a .text template and everything should work acceptably well.